# Can't access ListBox array to pass values from sheet to ListBox

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

As always, thank you for your help!

I need a ListBox to display values from a spreadsheet. For each cell in the sheet I test whether the item (a row) meets a criteria (here: "Sale") and then add the range to a ListBox. Thus, the ListBox should display only the items with "Sale" from the range. I'mn getting everything right except for some reason I'm not accesing the ListBox array index correctly. I've added few examples in comments of what's working and what's not:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    With ListBox1
        .Clear
        .ColumnHeads = True
        .ColumnCount = 9
        .ColumnWidths = "90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90"
        
        Dim cell As Range
        Dim lastrw As Long
        lastrw = inputws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For Each cell In inputws.Range("A2:A" & lastrw)
            If cell.Offset(0, 4).Value = "Sale" Then
                .List(.ListCount - 1, 0) = inputws.Cells(cell.Row, 5).Value
                .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = inputws.Cells(cell.Row, 6).Value
                'works, but not what I want
                '.List = inputws.Range("E2:E6").Value
                'works, but not what I want
                '.List = inputws.Range("E2:L6").Value
                'not working
                '.List(0, 0) = "text"
                'not working
                '.List(1, 1) = "text"
            End If
        Next

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to use `.AddItem` if you're doing it that way.